# Autofac - Resolving a dependency by request

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

How do I resolve a dependency when I don't want to get it through Construction Injection? The reason for it is that it would cause circular references and end up being a very long list (and scale badly).

In pseudo code I need something like this:

```
public ISummarizer GetSummarizer(Type requestedType)
{
    if (!requestedType.IsAssignableFrom(ISummarizer))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(
            "Trying to resolve a dependency that does not implement ISummarizer.");
    }

    return AutofacContainer.Resolve<requestedType>();
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Both reasons you give seems like symptoms of bad design. Cyclic dependencies can prevented by splitting up classes (often the source is Single Responsibility Principle violation). Having a 'long list' of dependencies should usually not 'scale badly'. Do you mind showing your design so we can feedback on that?

Comment: @Steven: You're correct, the cyclic dependency issue is easily fixed by moving the logic to a separate class. Why I thought it would scale badly is because I would have a single class with a dependency on all possible `ISummarizer` implementations (possibly easily 30+). That's not necessarily bad design than?

Comment: If you have a list of `ISummarizer` implementations, that would be quite common, and I am unsure why that wouldn't scale. Have you profiled this? But what you want to have is some sort of dispatcher/proxy implementation which is quite common and fine from a design perspective. But passing the exact summarizer type from the consumer might not be the best option.

Comment: Okay, I was just figuring, but I'll look into alternatives than. Probably a facade. I'll see if I can provide a meaningful answer when able, thanks for the input!